# iPhone : How do I display the user location on a map view without updating location / having GPS running in the background?

Tags: iphone, gps, location, mkmapview, power-management

how do I display the user location in a mapView while not running GPS to update the location (at all)? Will

```
mapView.userTrackingMode = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
```

do the job or will GPS still burn battery in the background?

Thanks :)

Comment: I think it will still run the GPS in the background.

Comment: :/ so how would you display the user location then ?

Comment: I suspect he wants the map to statically display (i.e. not move at all) while GPS and/or CoreLocation is programatically turned off, so the battery doesn't burn down as fast.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure... I don't do iOS development as much as I do web development. Why is battery such a big concern? As the developer, you should make your app "lean" and "light", but its the user's responsibility to charge their device every night.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann but I think he wants to "update the location all the time"... I think that means that the user is moving...

Comment: a static map would be perfectly fine :)

Comment: @lacsapF please edit your question to add a bit more context and useful detail:  you said "static map is fine", but then that also means the nothing (including the dot or annotation that denotes the user) would be moving either, yes?  Or do you want the map to stay still while the user's dot is moving within the map?  or?

Comment: You're essentially asking "how do I know the user's location without checking the user's location." It's not a meaningful question.

Comment: @MihirSingh Battery usage should always be a concern on iOS. A mobile device has limited battery life to share between all tasks and it is our responsibility as developers to make sure a user is not caught short because of us. This is also Apple's stance. They mention it heavily in the docs, especially when dealing with GPS

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan I did not ask that :) I want to check the user's location ONCE and then display it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to attempt to answer your question as best as i can given the limited information.

The GPS has 3 main modes that go from low power to high power, low accuracy to high accuracy.

- Location Tracking off
- Background location updates (uses cell towers and wifi)
- GPS location updates

An `MKMapView` will show a blue dot for the user location if you set `showsUserLocation` to `YES`. The `MKMapView` will use all available location methods to find the users location as accurately as possible and keep updating it while this is set to YES.

The tracking in `MKMapView`, a mode which keeps the users location centred on screen, moves the visible map region as the user moves and is available in iOS5. you are given three `MKUserTrackingMode`s to choose from. From the docs:

> MKUserTrackingModeNone: The map does not follow the user location.
>
> MKUserTrackingModeFollow: The map follows the user location.
>
> MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading: The map follows the user location
>   and rotates when the heading changes.

So setting it to `kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters` isn't going to work as it is not an available option in this context.

Will showing the location burn battery in the background? It depends on what you mean by background. When the user taps the home button the `MKMapView` is forced to stop using the GPS by the system. While the app is running and the MKMapView is alive and has the `showsUserLocation` property set to `YES` it will keep using any available method, including the GPS, to update the location. You have a couple of strategies to reduce this.

1) presume that the user needs to see their location updated while the map is on screen. In which case keep `showsUserLocation` set to YES until the map is moved off screen, or the device is locked, then set it to `NO`

2) Presume the user only needs to see a static marker of their location from a particular point in time, like when the app is opened. In this case you need to make a `CLLocationManager` object, ask it to `startUpdatingLocation`, filter the delegate messages for the accuracy you want, and then turn off location updates (`stopUpdatingLocation`). You can then add an `MKAnnotation` to the `MKMapView` to show the user their location.

As you can see number 2 is more work, yet very power efficient. Number 1 is easy, but will use more battery while the map is visible. It is up to you to decide which behaviour the user expects and to implement your app accordingly.